# Is it possible to add logical operators in hasClass() method?

Tags: jquery, operator-keyword

for example something like this

```
if($(this).hasClass('one'||'two'||'three'))
```

If it isn't possible, how should I change the code?

Answer (score 1):

No, won't work that way.

You have to use seperate expressions

```
if($(this).hasClass('one') || $(this).hasClass('two') ||$(this).hasClass('three')) {

}
```